# Create a global method to call in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am pretty new to MVC and I am currently working on an MVC 3 project in visual studio and I want to create a method or variable that is accessible globally.  When I say globally I mean available in my web project, service layer project, and data layer project.

I guess when I say global I mean global to the entire solution.

I tried creating a class in the solution items folder and referencing in my web project but its not letting me add a reference to the class since it is not a DLL.

I am a little confused with how to do this.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.  Also keep in mind that though I am a programmer I am still somewhat new to MVC and programming.

Edit:  I have also tried adding a method in the global.asax file but was unable to call it

Comment: NO! Try to find another solution that respects OOP. We have enough tightly coupled code out there.

Comment: What do you need global methods/variables for? There's probably a better way to design your project that avoids global data.

Comment: My Spidey-sense is tingling - this does not sound like a good idea. You should not have a dependant variable linked across multiple projects like that. I suggest you look at using session state via HttpContext.Current.Session[] to share data, for example. You can access that in any project, Web or Class Library, by referencing `System.Web`.

Comment: I am trying to add an offset for Time zones within the project that uses a getCurrentTime method as a substitute for DateTime.Now  I would need to call this getCurrentTime() method in my service layer and my web layer.  This method calls the database and retrives the time zone for our customers application instance.  It currently resides in my service layer but I don't want to have to add it to every model  I just want to be able to call the method directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a shared assembly where you define the class. You can then add a reference to the shared assembly from all projects that need the feature.

Answer (score 0):

The class that you want to be "global" sounds like some sort of service. I suppose this is the kind of thing you may want to do with a logging service for example.

Using a logging service as an example it is generally best practice for the interface to the logging service be defined in a lightweight contracts type assembly. Then any of your assemblies that require an implementation of `ILoggingService` should inject the necessary implementation using an IoC container such as [Autofac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/) or [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This pattern is pretty common and allows you to share common services while keeping implementations loosely coupled. Also this pattern will lead to highly testable code as fake implementations can be injected with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)